# Wordpress Order by date on custom post type archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-order-by, archive

I have a custom post type called city guide and i created a archive page with the following code in wordpress. The posts displays but not in the order.I need it with date and desc ordering. When i changed **$args** **orderby** and **order** from the below code but it was displaying the same.

```
<?php 

$args = array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'ASC' );
$taxonomy = 'city-guide-category';
$tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
foreach($tax_terms as $tt): 
$cat_arr[] = $tt->term_id;      
  endforeach;

 ?>
 <?php

    global $wp_query, $paged;

    if( get_query_var('paged') ){
        $paged = get_query_var('paged' );
    } else if ( get_query_var('page') ){
        $paged = get_query_var('page' );
    } else{
        $paged = 1;
    }
    ?>
     <?php $i=1; while( $wp_query->have_posts() ): $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

      <?php get_template_part( 'templates/content-city-guide', get_post_format() ); ?>

        <?php if( $i%2 == 0 && $i != $wp_query->post_count): ?>
            <div class="clearfix visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if( $i%3 == 0 && $i != $wp_query->post_count): ?>
          <div class="clearfix hidden-xs hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if( $i%4 == 0 && $i != $wp_query->post_count): ?>
            <div class="clearfix hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
     <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

I also tried

```
<?php 
$wp_query->set('orderby','date');
$wp_query->set('order','desc');
?>
```

before and also after

```
<?php $i=1; while( $wp_query->have_posts() ): $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
```

which also did not work.Where I am wrong.Please help me out.

I tried this

```
 <?php

    global $wp_query, $paged;

    if( get_query_var('paged') ){
        $paged = get_query_var('paged' );
    } else if ( get_query_var('page') ){
        $paged = get_query_var('page' );
    } else{
        $paged = 1;
    }

    //ddbug( $wp_query->request );

$args = array(
'orderby' => 'date',
'order'   => 'DESC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );  ?>
    <?php $i=1; while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>

      <?php get_template_part( 'templates/content-city-guide', get_post_format() ); ?>

        <?php if( $i%2 == 0 && $i != $query->post_count): ?>
            <div class="clearfix visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if( $i%3 == 0 && $i != $query->post_count): ?>
          <div class="clearfix hidden-xs hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if( $i%4 == 0 && $i != $query->post_count): ?>
            <div class="clearfix hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
 </div>

 <?php if( $query->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
  <div class="more-posts-link-wrapper">
    <?php next_posts_link(__('<span class="more-posts-text">More <i class="bits-arrow-down"></i></span><img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." class="ajax-loader" height="15px;" width="auto" style="display:none;">','roots') ); ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

It is displaying now by date but when i click the more link ore next page to see the second set of posts it is displaying the same set of posts.Imean theyre repeating even if i go to 12th page of pagination.
please help.

Comment: By the time you get to this code, it's pretty much too late to make any changes here, unless you go with a custom loop.  `$wp_query` is already set, and has already run.

Comment: i tried a custom loop but pagination doesnt seem to work . check edited code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters for more information. Slightly different to what you've already tried, try creating a new WP Query object.

EDIT to include pagination parameters in args, try something like

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
args = array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ($query->have_posts()){
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: hi i have added the edited code.it is working but pagination seems to have some problem.

Comment: I updated the post, take a look and see if it works for you. In the original query args there was only order by but pagination was also needed.

Comment: worked when tried with paged instead of page in ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page')

Comment: i have one qick qn , how can i display onl child pages and exclde parent pages from above code.please help

Comment: See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60292/wp-query-to-get-child-pages-of-current-page. I think it's what you're looking for. The post suggests adding 'post_parent'    => $post->ID and 'post_type' => 'page' to the args array.

Comment: thanks,that is for archive page of the current page children pages, actulay i want to display archive page of custom post type without parent posts :) hope you got it :)